# Time machine one folder?

Tags: time-machine

I want to back only one or some of my folder with time machine. Is it possible somehow to back them? And so I can maybe push down the datastore requirement down below 8GB, and so a flash drive will be enough to be always with me.

Comment: As far as I know, the only way to do this is to exclude everything else _except_ that one folder...

Comment: It sounds like the idea is less about having a backup, and more about how to make an automatically synced USB drive that you can take with you?

Comment: You might have right, I want a copy about my workspace folder, about the source code of my apps with me always

Comment: You might want to check the answers to this question at SuperUser:  http://superuser.com/questions/144702/mac-os-x-application-to-sync-a-folder-to-another-disk-in-real-time    You could also google for "folder action" &  "sync"